# Bundling jquery and Bootstrap in Gulp

Tags: jquery, gulp, bundle, bootstrap-4

I've set up the following gulp file

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var del = require("del");
var concat = require("gulp-concat");
var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
var sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
var rename = require("gulp-rename");

var paths = {
    wwwroot: {
        lib: "./wwwroot/lib"
    },
    lib: [
        "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
    ]
}

gulp.task("clean",
    function() {
        return del([paths.wwwroot.lib]);
    });

gulp.task("copy-lib", ["clean"],
    function () {
        return gulp.src(paths.lib)
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.wwwroot.lib));
    });

gulp.task("uglify", ["copy-lib"],
    function () {
        return gulp.src(paths.wwwroot.lib + "/**/*.js")
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(concat("bundle.js"))
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(isDebug, sourcemaps.write())
            .pipe(rename(addMinExtension))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.wwwroot.lib));
    });

gulp.task("default", ["clean", "uglify"],
    function () {
        del([paths.wwwroot.lib + "/**.*", "!" + paths.wwwroot.lib + "/*.min.js"]);
    });
```

This bundles and uglifies bootstrap in to a single js file. However, when I attempt to use this file in the browser I get the following error

```
bundle.min.js:1 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bundle.min.js:1
```

How can I ensure that bootstrap knows that I've bundled (`gulp-concat`) jquery so that it knows it's access to it. Am I missing a step in my bundling?

Comment: did you make any progress ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `jquery.js` is getting bundled only after `bootstrap.js` because your `uglify` task takes bootstrap first from `./wwwroot/lib`. I ran into similar issue some time back. Modifying your `uglify` task as below should work.

```
gulp.task("uglify", ["copy-lib"],
function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.wwwroot.lib + "/jquery.js", paths.wwwroot.lib + "/bootstrap.js"])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat("bundle.js"))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(isDebug, sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(rename(addMinExtension))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.wwwroot.lib));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the format that you used to add the jQuery and bootstrap.
I think problem is in the lines that you used to add `<script src>`
Please check this format:

**1) add JQuery library`<script type...`

2)Add bootstrap library`<script type...`

3) Add your plugin**

Comment: I'm bundling bootstrap and jquery so shouldn't there only be one `<script type...` in my html, i.e., `<script src="./wwwroot/lib/bundle.min.js/>`

Comment: Actually I didn't do this technique, anyway just try once by adding `<script src="" type="text/javascript">` src = JQuery cdn. Add this before bundle's src.

Comment: That will work, but kind of defeats the point in bundling doesn't it?

Comment: node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js or jquery.min. js,

Comment: surely it doesn't matter where i get it from, local or CDN, point is I shouldn't need to add the script tag for jquery if i'm bundling it all together in a single js.